# Laptop CPU frequency never higher than 40% of maximum

Tags: windows, laptop, power

I have a Samsung 900X4C (9 series) laptop with an i7 3517U 1.9 GHz CPU. I have noticed (using CPU-Z) that the actual frequency of the processor never goes above about 40% of the maximum. Now, I perfectly well understand that the CPU running at a frequency as low as possible is a *good thing*, as it lowers power consumption. However, sometimes, particularly when connected to mains power, I would like the CPU to run at maximum frequency. But it never does! Even having turned off all power saving features in the BIOS and in Windows, and having connected it to mains power, and then running a heavy CPU benchmark, it *never* runs at more than 40% of the maximum frequency. How can I make it run at max speed when I actually want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured this out myself. Samsung's "Settings" program has a "silent mode" (which bizarrely enough is not categorized under "power management"), that when activated or on "auto" basically never activates the fan, which forces the CPU to stay at a low frequency no matter what.